# Linearity of First ODE: A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

I have to determine the linearity of the following first ODE in differential form:

> $$(y^2-1)\ dx + x \ dy = 0$$

I have the following two forms which I have obtained from rearranged the form:

### Form 1

> $$(y^2-1)\ + \ x \ \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

My thoughts were that this one was nonlinear based on how it has the y squared.

### Form 2

> $$(y^2-1) \ \frac{dx}{dy} \ + \ x = 0$$

My thoughts were that this one was linear because it follows this format:

$$a(y)\frac{dx}{dy}+a(y)x=0$$

Is my intuition correct, and how do I determine which variable it is because the answer in the book says that its linear in x, and non-linear in y?

Comment: @Isham See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3526324/9003. Please answer in answer fields, and not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. First equation is not a first order linear DE 
$$y'x+ (y^2-1)=0$$
It's not of the form :
$$\alpha (x)y'+\beta (x) y=\gamma (x)$$
It's a Ricatti's equation of the form :
$$y'(x)=\alpha (x)+\beta (x) y+\gamma (x)y^2$$

The second DE is linear as you wrote:
$$x'(y^2-1)+x=0$$
And it's of the form:
$$\alpha (y)x'+\beta (y) x=\gamma (y)$$
Your intuition is correct. And both DE are separable.